# django-extra-views get current user

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am using `CreateWithInlinesView` from `django-extra-views`. How would I go about retrieving the current user in this case?

I have something like this currently

```
class PublisherCreateView(CreateWithInlinesView):
    model = Publisher
    inlines = [BookInline,]

    def form_valid(self, form, inlines):
        form.instance.created_by = self.request.user
        return super(PublisherCreateView, self).form_valid(form, inlines)
```

and this still returns the error of `(1048, "Column 'created_by_id' cannot be null")`.

edit: made my edit into an answer

Comment: You should add your solution as an answer and accept it.

Comment: iI lack the reputation to do this immediately but I shall do so in 5 hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    def forms_valid(self, form, inlines):
        form.instance.created_by = self.request.user
        return super(PublisherCreateView, self).forms_valid(form, inlines)
```

This is because `CreateWithInlinesView` subclasses a `BaseCreateWithInlinesView` with the `forms_valid()` method that calls `form_valid()` on the form itself and its inlines.

Comment: And how to do this with inlines? I did this :

`for inline in inlines:

            if inline.has_changed():

                for form in inline.forms:

                    if form.has_changed():

                        form.instance.changed_by = self.request.user`


But then the ID for foreignKey is not filling up and I get `inline_model.parent_id may not be NULL`

Comment: sorry for formatting -I tried but is obviously not possible in comment

Comment: is this block of code within `forms_valid`? If so, do you call `forms_valid` of the superclass (`CreateWithInlinesView`)?